# If A and B are elementary sets, then A - B is elementary.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, set-theory

Hello I am reviewing my notes, but I do not understand the last step well, could you explain why that happens?

If $A=\bigcup_{k}^{}P_{k}$  and  $B=\bigcup_{j}^{}Q_{j}$

where $P_k,Q_j$ are disjoint rectangles two by two

Demonstration
$$A-B=\bigcup_{k}^{}(P_{k}-B)$$Now I don't understand why$$P_{k}-B=\bigcap_{j}^{n}(P_k-Q_j)$$

I thought
$$P_{k}-B=P_k \bigcap B^{c}=P_k \bigcap (\bigcup_{j}^{}Q_{j})^{c}$$The DeMorgan's$$P_k \bigcap (\bigcap_{j}^{}Q_{j}^{c})=\bigcap_{j}^{}(P_k \bigcap Q_{j}^{c})=\bigcap_{j}^{}(P_k - Q_{j})$$

But,$ P_k \bigcap (\bigcap_{j}^{}Q_{j}^{c})=\bigcap_{j}^{}(P_k \bigcap Q_{j}^{c})$It is right?, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that "set difference" (\setminus) is defined as follows: $A \setminus B = A \cap B^c$.

Thus: $$P_k \setminus B=P_k \setminus \bigcup_j Q_j= P_k \cap (\bigcup_j Q_j)^c= [\text { by De Morgan} ] P_k \cap (\bigcap_j Q_j^c)=\bigcap_j(P_k \cap Q_j^c)=\bigcap_j(P_k \setminus Q_j).$$